# No ViewModelStoreOwner was provided via LocalViewModelStoreOwner

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I'm currently migrating a RecyclerView to use Compose. We decided to se a bottom-up approach by individually converting the viewholder item views to use a `ComposeView`, which contains a composable.

I am currently migrating a rather complex view to a composable, and it requires a viewmodel. We use Dagger2 for dependency injection, as our rather large codebase made a migration to Hilt be a larger scope, so that was put on the backburner.

Anyway, when I build and run, the recyclerview renders fine, and the composables are rendering within the recyclerview. However, as I scroll, when there are multiple `DataItemComposables` on the screen, the app crashes with the following stacktrace:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No ViewModelStoreOwner was provided via LocalViewModelStoreOwner
        at com.****.****.viewHolders.DataItemViewHolder$bindData$1$1$1.invoke(DataItemViewHolder.kt:42)
        at com.****.****.viewHolders.DataItemViewHolder$bindData$1$1$1.invoke(DataItemViewHolder.kt:41)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.RecomposeScopeImpl.compose(RecomposeScopeImpl.kt:140)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl.recomposeToGroupEnd(Composer.kt:2156)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl.skipToGroupEnd(Composer.kt:2422)
        at com.****.****.compose.theme.ThemeKt.MaterialTheme(Theme.kt:142)
```

The asterisks are just scrubbed out package names.

My code is as follows:

DataItemViewHolder.kt

```
override fun bindData(dataItem: DataItem, position: Int) {
        binding.root.apply {
            // Dispose the Composition when the view's LifecycleOwner
            // is destroyed
            setViewCompositionStrategy(ViewCompositionStrategy.DisposeOnViewTreeLifecycleDestroyed)
            setContent {
                MaterialTheme {
                     DataItemComposable(
                        repository = repository,
                        postId = dataItem.id,
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

DataItemComposable.kt

```
@Composable
fun DataItemComposable(
    repository: DataRepository,
    postId: String,
) {
    val viewModel: DataItemViewModel = viewModel(
        factory = DataItemViewModel.DataItemViewModelFactory(
            repository,
            itemId
        )
    )

    var state by remember { viewModel.itemState }
    Box {
        // Content using state
    }

}
```

DataItemViewModel.kt

```
class DataItemViewModel(
    private val repository: DataRepository,
    private val itemId: String
) : ViewModel() {
    val itemState = mutableStateOf("")

    // ...DO some stuff with the parameters
    ...
    ...
    ...



    /* ===== Factory ===== */
    public class DataItemViewModelFactory(
        val repository: DataRepository,
        val postId: String
    ) :
        ViewModelProvider.NewInstanceFactory() {
        override fun <T : ViewModel?> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T = 
        DataItemViewModel(
            repository,
            postId
        ) as T
    }   
}
```

Comment: Hey, did you manage to find a solution? I'm having a similar issue and can't figure it out

Comment: Can you check my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73332696/5155371
Maybe it helps for you as well?

Answer (score 3):

**Solution:**

```
  override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
         val view = ComposeView()

         view.setViewTreeViewModelStoreOwner(parent.findViewTreeViewModelStoreOwner())

        return ViewHolder(view)
    }
```

**Explanation:**

We were also facing the same crash while getting viewModel which was causing because of below code :

```
public inline fun <reified VM : ViewModel> viewModel(
viewModelStoreOwner: ViewModelStoreOwner = checkNotNull(LocalViewModelStoreOwner.current) {
    "No ViewModelStoreOwner was provided via LocalViewModelStoreOwner"
}
```

As you can see **LocalViewModelStoreOwner.current** is getting null hence we are getting this Error message.

It is happening because of **Default** **ViewCompositionStrategy** which is **ViewCompositionStrategy.DisposeOnDetachedFromWindowOrReleasedFromPool** as of now.

So now let's see what options do we currently have:

**Solution 1:**

We can use **DisposeOnDetachedFromWindow** but then it will reduce the performance.

**Solution 2:**

We can pass the **viewModel** from outside but then it is cumbersome to pass it to all the Items. We will lose the benefit of **viewModel()** method by this way

**Above two solutions are not mine, I just wrote them because I want to tell why I haven't used them in my case. So I just mentioned them for the comparison.

**My Solution :**

First we will get the **ViewTreeViewModelStoreOwner** and then pass it to **ComposeView** inside onCreate. Simple and Easy.

```
view.setViewTreeViewModelStoreOwner(parent.findViewTreeViewModelStoreOwner())
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it's the same issue, but I've solved it by adding this in the adapter:

```
override fun onViewRecycled(holder: MyComposeViewHolder) {
    // Dispose the underlying Composition of the ComposeView
    // when RecyclerView has recycled this ViewHolder
    holder.composeView.disposeComposition()
}
```

As stated in the documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/interop/compose-in-existing-ui#compose-recyclerview)

My guess is that somehow when the old composable was hanging in there instead of being dispose of, creating the exception.

Answer (score 1):

I could solve this bug by moving the viewModel access from the Composables to the parent `Fragment`. Then pass the instance to the `RecyclerView`s adapter.

```
class FooBarFragment: Fragment() {
    // Access the ViewModel from the fragment scope
    private val viewModel by viewModels<FooBarViewModel>()

    private val rvAdapter = object : RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>() {

        override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
            val composeView = holder.itemView as? ComposeView ?: return
            // Now you can use the ViewModel in your composable
            composeView.setContent { Text(text = viewModel.getText(position)) }
        }

        override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int) //..

        override fun getItemCount() //..
    }

    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue but none of the answers so far helped.
The crash happened for me when the `Composable` was part of a `RecyclerView`, which seems also to be the case for the OP. Then scrolling away during the view model's loading state made the app crash.

**Fix:**

The fix was as easy as setting a different composition strategy on the `ComposeView`:

```
setViewCompositionStrategy(ViewCompositionStrategy.DisposeOnDetachedFromWindow)
```

**Explanation**:

If you check the kDocs, the fix makes actually sense, me and the OP used `DisposeOnViewTreeLifecycleDestroyed`, however this strategy is not meant for `RecyclerView` usage:

```
 /**
 * [ViewCompositionStrategy] that disposes the composition when the [ViewTreeLifecycleOwner]
 * of the next window the view is attached to is [destroyed][Lifecycle.Event.ON_DESTROY].
 * This strategy is appropriate for Compose UI views that share a 1-1 relationship with
 * their closest [ViewTreeLifecycleOwner], such as a Fragment view.
 */
```

Here the kDocs for the `DisposeOnDetachedFromWindow`:

```
 /**
 * [ViewCompositionStrategy] that disposes the composition whenever the view becomes detached
 * from a window. If the user of a Compose UI view never explicitly calls
 * [AbstractComposeView.createComposition], this strategy is always safe and will always
 * clean up composition resources with no explicit action required - just use the view like
 * any other View and let garbage collection do the rest. (If
 * [AbstractComposeView.createComposition] is called while the view is detached from a window,
 * [AbstractComposeView.disposeComposition] must be called manually if the view is not later
 * attached to a window.)
 */
```

Answer (score 0):

This solved it for me.

```kotlin
composeView.apply {
    setViewCompositionStrategy(ViewCompositionStrategy.DisposeOnDetachedFromWindow)
    setContent {
        HomeItemView()
    }
}
```